# Does the expression $ \sum_{k,j=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k b_j $ make sense?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Let 
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k \, ,  \qquad  \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} b_k 
$$
be two absolutely convergent complex series.

Does the expression 
$$
\sum_{k,j=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k b_j
$$

make sense? Why?

What about
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k b_j
$$
?

Can one write 
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k b_j = \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k \right)\left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} b_k \right)
$$
?

Comment: You should look at the Fubini-Tonelli theorem (with your measure being counting measure).